# Как формировать словарь через цикл в GoogleAppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Изначально из таблицы Google Sheets я вытягиваю названия колонок с помощью функции:

```
function getColValuesName() {
  
  var maxColumns = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn();
  var values_column = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 1, 1, maxColumns).getValues();

  return values_column[0]
}
```

После этого мне нужно их преобразовать в словарь, который в результате должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
    {name: 'values_column1', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'values_column2', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'values_column3', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'values_column4', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'values_column5', type: 'STRING'},
    {name: 'values_column6', type: 'STRING'}
```

*Не могу разобраться как это можно реализовать с помощью цикла...*

Answer (score 0):

Если по правильному то тянуть две строки
Заголовка и ниже 1 потом

```js
function getColValuesName() {
  var maxColumns = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getLastColumn();
  var values= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
    .getRange(1, 2, 1, maxColumns).getValues();
 return values[0].reduce(
    (acc,col,i)=>{
      return {...acc,{name:col,type:type of values[1][i]}
    },{}
  );
}
```

Comment: Подскажите, зачем требуется тянуть две строки?